# Що таке "бест"? Словосполучення "в бесті дожидати"

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, фразеологізми, сталий-вираз

У О. Мізерницького в "Ганусі":

> — Диви!.. Відколи такого не бачили... Я думав, що такі вже давно перевелись, а вони... — резонує дядько з возу.
>
> — Десь, мабуть, в бесті  свого часу дожидали... ну й дождали, — одповідає йому другий.

На [ulif](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96) є лише в пошуковому сервісі, а [тут](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) вже немає. На [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/best) немає. На [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82*&scope=ukr&dicts=all&highlight=on) також немає. Не знайшов навіть в етимолоґічному словнику.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Спочатку я не знайшов на всіх цих сайтах інформації, але потім натрапив на [Словник іншомовник слів](http://slovopedia.org.ua/36/53393/235229.html) на Словопедії:

> БЕСТ (перс.)
>
> 1. Засноване на старовинному звичаї **право притулку** (недоторканності) в Ірані на території священних і недоторканних місць (напр., мечеті, будинки вищих духовних осіб, іноземні посольства), *звідки людину, що її переслідує влада, не можна взяти силою*.
> 2. перен. ***сісти в бест*** - *сховатися від переслідування, вичікувати зміни обставин.*

Отже, слово походить від перської мови, в якій значить "право притулку на території священних і недоторканних місць, звідки людину не можна взяти силою", а в українській мові прижилося у виразі "сидіти в бесті" / "дожидати в бесті" - переховуватися від переслідування, вичікуючи на зміну обставин.